# Javascript Date validation not working on android device 4.4.4

Tags: javascript, android, validation, cordova

I am developing phone gap application.In application I used html textbox for inputing date from user and I wrote date validation code using javascript. When I run the application on emulator date validation is working fine. But when I run the application on android device date validation not working.

Device:Micromax AQ4501
Device Version:Android Kitkat 4.4.4
Emulator:Android 4.4.2

Code:

```
var isShift=false;
var seperator = "/";
function DateFormat(txt , keyCode)
{

 if(keyCode==16)
     isShift = true;
 //Validate that its Numeric
 if(((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || keyCode == 8 ||
     keyCode <= 37 || keyCode <= 39 ||
     (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105)) && isShift == false)
 {
     if ((txt.value.length == 2 || txt.value.length==5) && keyCode !=   
     8)
    {
        txt.value += seperator;
    }
    return true;
 }
 else
 {
     return false;
 }
}

 function ValidateDate(txt,keyCode)
 {
 //alert("validate function called");
  if(keyCode==16)
     isShift = false;
 var val=txt.value;
 if(val.length == 10)
  {
    var splits = val.split("/");
    var dt = new Date(splits[1] + "/" + splits[0] + "/" + splits[2]);
    alert(dt);
    //Validation for Dates
     if(dt.getDate()==splits[0] && dt.getMonth()+1==splits[1]
               && dt.getFullYear()==splits[2])
        {
         //do nothing  
        }

      else
       {
          return;
       }

       //Range Validation
       if(txt.id.indexOf("txtRange") != -1)
          RangeValidation(dt);

       //BirthDate Validation
       if(txt.id.indexOf("txtBirthDate") != -1)               
        BirthDateValidation(dt)
       }
       else if(val.length < 10)      
       {　  　         //do nothing
       }
       }

function BirthDateValidation(dt)
{
 var dtToday = new Date();
 var pastDate = new Date(Date.parse(dtToday.getMonth()+"/"+
    dtToday.getDate()+"/"+parseInt(dtToday.getFullYear()-100)));
 if (dt<pastDate || dt>=dtToday)
 {
   alert("Invalid BirthDate");
 }
 else
 {

     alert("Valid BirthDate");
  }
  }

 function RangeValidation(dt)
 {
 var startrange = new Date(Date.parse("01/01/1900"));
 var endrange = new Date(Date.parse("12/31/2099"));
 //var lblmesg = document.getElementById("<%=lblMesg.ClientID%>") ;
 if (dt<startrange || dt>endrange)
 {

     alert("Date should be between 01/01/1900 and 31/12/2099");
  }
  }
```

Comment: can you give more details on the "not working"? maybe provide an example

Comment: @jcesarmobile When I use Micromax AQ4501 device and tried to enter a character like a , b etc it does allow in date textbox. So the  validation is not working. But when I used emulator and tried to give the character in date textbox it wont allow, so validation is working on emulator.